# Converting the result in_array into an array

Tags: php

I am trying to extract some checkboxes values into an array. My problem is **array($is_types)**. I am expecting $is_types to be an array, say array(one, two, three):

```
<?php
  if (!is_array($types)) {
    $types = array();
  }
  $filtered_array = array_filter($types);

 $is_types = in_array($type, $filtered_array);

  $output = _get_array(array($is_types), $bla, $bla2);
?>
```

**UPDATE:**
I need to rephrase what I am trying to achieve. 
I have some checkboxes with options: one, two, three, etc. Only when I check them, the options should be stored. Checking what are stored is enough with $is_types, returning the bool. 
Then I have a need to do other queries to aggregate content based on these checked checkboxes. That is if I have an array(one, two, three), based on the filtered checkboxes, then  run the query

**UPDATE2:**

```
function _get_array($type, $view_mode, $limit = NULL) {

  $node = menu_get_object();
  $build = array();

  $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
  $created = isset($node) ? $node->created : 'now';
  $query
    ->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
    ->entityCondition('bundle', $type, is_array($type) ? 'IN' : '=')
    ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
    ->propertyOrderBy('created', 'DESC')
    ->propertyCondition('created', $created, '<');

  if ($limit != NULL) {
    $query->range(0, $limit);
  }

  $result = $query->execute();

  if (!empty($result['node'])) { 
    $nodes = entity_load('node', array_keys($result['node']));
    $build[] = node_view_multiple($nodes, $view_mode);

  }
  return !empty($build) ? $build : array();
}
```

The checkboxes are just checkboxes with some values.
So querying _get_array(array($is_types), $bla, $bla2); should load all nodes filtered by these checkboxes value.

Any hint would be very much appreciated. Thanks

UPDATE3:
Thanks to all. The answer was there all along. What I need seems just: $filtered_array

Comment: `in_array` will return a **boolean**. So what exactly do you want `$is_types` to look like?

Comment: What is your end goal? `in_array` returns a bool, not array. You can *cast* it to an array, but I suspect that is not what you want?

Comment: array($is_types) should be array(one, two, three); Thanks

Comment: Where would `one, two, three` come from? `in_array` tells you whether a specific element occurs in the array. How is it supposed to resolve to `one, two, three`?

Comment: Even your update doesn't make things much clearer. Can you simply **provide sample input and the expected output**?

Comment: do you want to store values from all checked checkboxes into array?

Comment: @timmay: Checkboxes are stored fine, but I have further need to extract those bools into an array, if possible. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I understand what you mean. You probably have the following HTML...

```
<input type="checkbox" name="test" value="one"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="test" value="two"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="test" value="three"/>
```

And on the server, you want an array containing one, two or three depending on which were selected.

Basically, you have to add square brackets to 'test' to tell PHP to consider `test` as an array, like so:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="one"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="two"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="three"/>
```

And on the server, you simply access this as follows:

```
print_r( $_REQUEST['test'] );
```

Beware that if none of the options were selected, you won't get an array. Instead, do the following:

```
$options = isset( $_REQUEST['test'] ) ? $_REQUEST['test'] : array();
```

To ensure all variables are legit, do the following:

```
$legit = array('one','two','three');

foreach($options as $n=>$option)
    if(!in_array( $option, $legit ))
        unset( $options[ $n ] );
```

Comment: I am not sure this array is the filtered ones, is it?

Comment: The answer is there all along. I was distracted that I need to extract the bools, while accessing $filtered_array already returns the expected values. Thanks a lot to all for educations. I learned.

Comment: @swan: I don't even think you need `array_filter`. Only the values of selected checkboxes will be sent to the server (if that's it what you care about).

Comment: @Felix. Thanks. But last time I run it without array_filter, the CMS do not store them into the variables table. Maybe should, but not, unfortunately.